# Magento2 Add Layout Handle Dynamically Depending On Product Attribute Catalog_Product_View

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog

I have tried this with plugins and preferences and I seem to be missing the best practise method.

Why would Magento render the page so early that you can't modify the layout via plugin?

Am I missing something here?

I want to add an extra layout handle if the product has a certain attribute with x value. What is best practise here?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it isn't necessary to use a plugin if the event is provided.

Try use the event

> layout_load_before

The event is dispatched in

> \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder:

```
protected function loadLayoutUpdates()
{
    Profiler::start('LAYOUT');
    /* dispatch event for adding handles to layout update */
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'layout_load_before',
        ['full_action_name' => $this->request->getFullActionName(), 'layout' => $this->layout]
    );
    Profiler::start('layout_load');
    $this->layout->getUpdate()->load();

    Profiler::stop('layout_load');
    Profiler::stop('LAYOUT');
    return $this;
}
```

Actually I think that magento 2 plugins is rather powerful feature, but, let me say, it breaks out of the application architecture. I’d rather prefer the event usage to the plugin usage.

Comment: This would run for every layout load for the sake of one type of product. I just can't bring myself to do it.

Comment: You can check in your own observer class any product parameter,  attribute or attribute set. Only if it correspond your specific condition - add layout handle to layout.

Comment: It is an example for magento 1 - but I assume, for magento 2 there are no essential distinctions: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/

Comment: Would you recommend this with performance in mind?

Comment: I can't see any performance problem, using the event only for the product page with simplest verification by product attribute.